# A tool which checks that a local version of a site is fully translated (for continuous integration)

Tags: web-services, localization, translation, web-crawler

I'm working on a project, in which we design a localized version of an existing site (written in English) for another country (which is not English-speaking). And the business requirement is "no English text for all possible and impossible cases".

Does anyone know if there is a checker software/service which could check if a site is fully translated, that is which checks that there are no English text in it.

I new that there are sites for checking broken links, html validity etc, I need something like http://validator.w3.org/checklink but for checking that on all pages of the site there is no English text.

The reasons I think this way is needed are:
1. There is a lot of code which is common (both on backend and frontend) for all countries
2. If someone commits anything to the common code I need to be sure that this will not lead to english text issues in localized version. 
3. From business point of view it is preferable that site does not support some functionality, than it shows english text ( legal matters)
4. The code both on frontend and backend changes a lot 
5. There are a lot of files which affect text on the client's screen. Not just one with messages, unfortunately. And some of messages comes from backend, but most of them are in frontend
6. Due to all those fact currently someone manually fills all the forms and watch with his own eyes, and that is before each deploy...

Comment: What constitutes "English text"?

Comment: I thought of replacing the English resources with garbage text. Then, if you ever get back anything but the garbage, then that's a resource that has been localized. Whether it's been localized correctly or not is a different question.

Comment: Well, the problem actually is not just truslate it and forget, the problem is that we need to ensure that in "continuous integration" fation. That is if some another developer changes something in common part of code, then before deploying localized version we can be sure that no english text will appear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching the problem from the wrong direction. You're looking for an algorithm or webcrawler that can detect wether any text is English or not? I don't know, but I doubt such a thing even exists.

If you have translated the website, you have full access to the codebase and/or translation texts, right? Can't you just open both the English and non-English strings files (.resx or whatever you are using) in a comparetool like Notepad++ to check the differences to see if there are any missing strings? And check the sourcecode and verify that all parts that can output user-displayable text use the meta:resourceKey property (or whatever you are using).

Comment: Comparing the translation with the original is probably the best way to go — better than web crawling since the crawler won't find all the error situations (impossible cases).

Comment: That is difficult, s.a. the FE is on drupal, back end is on .net. And FE in some cases just shows responses from BE as is. And the both of them have special logic for each country, and some special. And there were cases when some one added somthing to common part of code and on polish version english text appears. Besides noone thought that not-english countries would be the case from the beginning.  Plus the project size... Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, web crawlers usually dont't execute javascripts so they would not find everything. but I know an example of broken link checkers which could fill the form on a site, that would be much better than nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the way of crawling, I'm not aware of an existing crawler that does this, but it sounds like a combination of two simple issues:

1. Finding existing open-source code for a web crawler should be dead simple
2. Identifying a language through n-gram analysis is trivial if there's a limited number of languages the text can be in.

The only difficult part would be to ensure that the analyzer always has a decent chunk of text to work with. You could extract stuff paragraph by paragraph. For forms you'd probably have to combine the text of several form labels.

Comment: Yep, it could be done this way.  I've created an open-source project for this need : https://github.com/bogdartysh/languagechecker-crawler. It's far from production-ready, but one can try to improve and use it freely, Thanks